# Yii2 ActiveCheckboxList item checked event

Tags: jquery, yii2

Is there a way to capture which item was checked in an ActiveCheckboxList, so as to be able to modify the form based on that value?

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'options')->checkBoxList($options) ?>
```

This generates (as expected) an HTML

```
<div id="classname-options">
```

tag enclosing a series of checkbox input types with name, value, and data-index. When a specific option is checked, I want to toggle hide/unhide another field on the form.

With a single checkbox, I have always assigned an id to its input tag and used a js handler.  But I don't know how to do that with a checkbox list, so I assumed I have to check the value in the DOM...?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is what I did to make this work.  Essentially, JQuery change event handler on the containing div checks each checkbox in the list for the value -- in my example I am looking for "CC."  (I don't know in advance which item has the value, so I couldn't check by data-index.)

Here is the JS in my view file.:

```
<?php 
$script = <<< JS
$(function() {
        $('#otherfieldlbl').hide();
        $('#otherfield').hide();
})
$('#member-options').change(function() {
    var ccexists = false;
    $('#member-options input:checked').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('value') == 'CC') {
            ccexists = true;
        }
    });
    if (ccexists == true) {
        $('#otherfieldlbl').show();
        $('#otherfield').show();
    } else {
        $('#otherfieldlbl').hide();
        $('#otherfield').hide();
    };
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

Please let me know if you have a better way.  Otherwise, hope this helps someone else.